# Regular expression: At least two a's and doesn't end in bb

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I've just started to learn about regular expressions and don't think I've got the hang of things at all. One of the problems I am looking at asks for a regular expression for all words over the alphabet {a, b} that contains at least two a's and doesn't end in bb.

So far I've got the following based on some other examples I found...

b*a(b*aa*(ba)*b)

Is this correct?

Comment: If you are being asked for an example of a regular expression over $\{a,b\}$ that has at least two $a$s and doesn't end in $bb$, simply consider $aa$. It has two $a$s but does not end in $bb$. Are you being asked to count the number of such words with a certain length?

Comment: @aston: No, the question is as stated: to write a regular expression that represents the specified language.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposal, `b*a(b*aa*(ba)*b)` is not correct.  For example, the string `aaaaa` has “at least two `a`s and does not end in `bb`”, but your proposed expression does not match it, because every string matched by your expression will end with `b`.

I suggest you try it like this:  If it doesn't end in `bb` it must end in one of `ab`, `ba`, or `aa`.  (Or it could be shorter than 2 symbols, but if so it would fail to contain at least 2 `a`s, so we can disregard this possibility.)

If it ends in `aa` then what might the rest of the string look like?  What restrictions are on it?  Try writing a regular expression for “contains at least 2 `a`s and ends with `aa`”.

Then write a second expression for “contains at least 2 `a`s and ends with `ab`”, and a third expression for “contains at least 2 `a`s and ends with `ba`”.

Then the answer to your problem is just the union of the three expressions.

Do you think you can do that?

Comment: Ok I've tried something else: a\*ab\*aa\*(b + E)((a+bb\*a)a(1 + E))\*. Does that make sense? I should point out this is something I'm endeavouring to learn so I'm pooling from loads of resources... Some of the notation I've found to be inconsistent.

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense, and it's kind of a mess.  Just like you, I don't have a magic ability to look at a regex and see what language it represents.  If you want to answer this question, and more important if you want the grader to recognize that your answer is correct, you need to be more methodical.

Comment: Except I don't know that that `1` in there means.  That definitely doesn't make sense.

Comment: And I now see (after asking the computer for help) that the word `ab` is matched by that regex, but it should not be.

Answer (score 1):

In case this troublesome question was keeping anyone up at night, here is the solution that I eventually figured out!

b∗ab∗(a ∪ b)∗(a ∪ ab)